# Binding Imagesource in xaml Windows Universal

Tags: image, xaml, binding

I need to Bind my imagesource to a uri which is made up by one static uri and one uri which I try to bind in front of the static uri.
I already included the binding but I can't put the static uri in front of it:
**Notice: I'm developing for the Windows Universal Platform**

```
 <Image Source="{Binding InventoryItem.properties.icon_url}"> //Here needs to be the static uri in front of the binding
                                        </Image>
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Could you write an example of what value takes icon_url? is a complete uri or you need to transform it?

Comment: the icon_url is a specific part for example the static url is:"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/" and the changing url (icon_url) is e.g. "3190499". I solved this problem already inc c# by combining this urls for each list item, but it would be interesting to get a more easy xaml solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood well the solution is the following:

1.- Create a Converter:

```
namespace Converters
{
public class UriConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        string relativepath = value as String;
        BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
        bi.UriSource = new Uri($"http://www.yourwebsite.com/{relativepath}.png");
        return bi;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
}
```

2.- Then add into your XAML

```
<Page... xmlns:c="using:Converters">
<Page.Resources>
 <c:UriConverter x:Key="UriConverter"/>
 </Page.Resources>

 <Image Source="{Binding InventoryItem.properties.icon_url, Converter={StaticResource UriConverter}}"/>
...
</Page>
```

You can instance the resource Converter in the App.xaml if you need in several places.